# How can I prove this series is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Let $x_{n}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers and let $y_{n}=x_{n}-x_{n+1}$ for each $n$ in $N$.
Prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} y_{n}$ is convergent and find the sum. How can I show that this series is convergent? So far I have

Proof: Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} y_{n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}-x_{n+1}$ for each $n$ in $N$. Then,$S_{n}=(x_{1}-x_{2})+(x_{2}-x_{3})+(x_{3}-x_{4})+...+(x_{n}-x_{n+1})$. So, $S_{n}=x_{1}-x_{n+1}$.

Comment: what is $$x_{n+1}$$?

Comment: Not having any idea how $x_i$ are defined we can't have any idea.  But if $x_i$ converges to $L$ then this limit is $x_1 - L$.  But somehow I doubt that is what the problem is going for.

Comment: Oh, and if this x_i doesn't converge then neither does this.  BTW did you write don't the question right? (Well, obviously not because you left out all the important information) But I'm wondering if the question was supposed to be $x_n - x_{n+1}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the question is saying let $x_{n}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers and let $y_{n}=x_{n}-x_{n+1}$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\inf y_{n}$ is convergent and find the sum. So I found $Sn=x_{1}-x_{n+1}$ and I'm trying to find this limit.

Comment: It is $x_1-lim x_n $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k y_{n} = x_1 - x_{k+1}$

The partial sums of 
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty y_{n}$ form a convergent sequnce

Comment: I'm not understanding why they form a convergent sequence? No one has explained that yet.

Comment: let $s_k = x_1 - x_{k+1}$ be the partial sum of the series.  Since the series $\{x_n\}$ is convergent, there exists an $N>0$ such that when  $m,n>N\implies|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon.$  For the same $m,n,  |y_n-y_m| = |x_{m+1}-x_{n+1}|< \epsilon.$